# WSO2 BAM 2.4.1 upgrade to DAS 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-bam

Im going to upgrade BAM 2.4.1 to DAS 3.0.0. In there, I have few questions to clarify there

1. Im going to use https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Upgrading+from+WSO2+BAM+2.5.0 documentation, Is that OK to use it  as BAM 2.4.1 and BAM 2.5 use same Platform  and kernel versions?
2. My other products (IS, API manager, and BPS) use 4.2.0 kernel and platform version, so is there any issue when I use DAS 3.0.0  with other products as DAS kernal version and platform version different.

Could you please share  your thought

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use BAM 2.5.0 and Update to DAS 3.0.0. You have 2 options to do the update.

1. Update BAM 2.4.1 to BAM 2.5.0 by using BAM documentation [1] and then update that BAM 2.5.0 to DAS 3.0.0 by using DAS documentation [2]
2. Since DAS is a completely different product, if your implementation is not a complicated one, its better to implement DAS manually.

Compatibility issues depend on how you have integrated old BAM with IS, BPS and APIM. Initially you cannot install 4.2.0 old features on DAS 3.0.0. If you have used BAM to save APIM statistics, you have to create required receivers, streams in DAS 3.0.0 but as both DAS and BAM use thrift you can integrate with other old products. Its always recommend to update other products as well.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Upgrading+from+WSO2+BAM+2.5.0